# Flutter: version 0.2.8 does not allow a Future to return another Future of different type

Tags: future, flutter

Before I update to the last version of Flutter (see below), the following code extract used to work, now I receive exception.

The objective of this piece of code is to invoke a Future which will return an answer resulting from a AJAX call to my server.

With the new version of Flutter (0.2.8), using Dart 2.0.0, it seems that a Future < T > cannot return another Future < String > (of another type) [see code below].

I do not find the answer.  Could anyone help me?

Many thanks

Flutter version:

```
flutter --version
Flutter 0.2.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b397406561 (12 days ago) • 2018-04-02 13:53:20 -0700
Engine • revision c903c217a1
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.43.0.flutter-52afcba357
```

Code extract:

```
  ///
  /// Returns the list of items belonging to the active profile
  /// 
  Future<PageAnswer> getItems({
    int pageIndex: 0,
    int pageSize: 50,
    @required String sortOrder
  }) async {
    String url = "ItemsList/$sortOrder";

    return ajaxGet(url).then((String responseBody) async {

      final Map response = json.decode(responseBody);
      final _status = response["status"];
      if (_status == "OK"){
          // Everything is OK
          Map map = json.decode(response["data"]);
          List<Map> objects = map["List"];
          int total = map["Total"];
          return new PageAnswer(objects, total);
      }
      return Null;
    }).catchError((){
      return Null;
    });
  }
```

Http Get implementation:

```
/// ----------------------------------------------------------
/// Http "GET" request
/// ----------------------------------------------------------
Future<String> ajaxGet(String serviceName) async {
  var responseBody = '{"data": "", "status": "NOK"}';
  try {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var uri = new Uri.http(mid.serverUrl, _serverApi + serviceName);
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(uri);

    request.headers
      ..add('X-mobile-uuid', await _getDeviceIdentity())
      ..add('X-mobile-token', await mid.getMobileToken());

    var response = await request.close();
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      responseBody = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
    }
  } catch(e){
    // An error was received
    print("AJAX ERROR");
  }
  return responseBody;
}
```

Code invocation:

```
PageAnswer answer = await getItems(sortOrder: 'alpha');
...
```

Types:

```
typedef Future<PageAnswer> ApiPageRequest(int page, int pageSize);

class PageAnswer {
  final List<Map> list;
  final int total;

  PageAnswer(this.list, this.total);
}
```

Exception Stack:

```
E/flutter ( 6926): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 6926): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<PageAnswer>' where
E/flutter ( 6926):   Future is from dart:async
E/flutter ( 6926):   FutureOr is from dart:async
E/flutter ( 6926):   PageAnswer is from file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/libraries/function_types.dart
E/flutter ( 6926):
E/flutter ( 6926): #0      MIDApi.getItems (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/libraries/api.dart:39:22)
E/flutter ( 6926): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6926): #1      _LandingPageState.doSomething (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/pages/landing.dart:129:39)
E/flutter ( 6926): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6926): #2      _LandingPageState._handleTap (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/pages/landing.dart:124:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #3      _LandingPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/pages/landing.dart:61:26)
E/flutter ( 6926): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter ( 6926): #5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
E/flutter ( 6926): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:123:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #7      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 6926): #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:147:20)
E/flutter ( 6926): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
E/flutter ( 6926): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #13     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:13)
E/flutter ( 6926): #14     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:5)


E/flutter ( 6926): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 6926): type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr<Null>'
E/flutter ( 6926): #0      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:145:11)
E/flutter ( 6926): #1      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:645:47)
E/flutter ( 6926): #2      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666:24)
E/flutter ( 6926): #3      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:485:5)
E/flutter ( 6926): #4      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:55:12)
E/flutter ( 6926): #5      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:27:5)
E/flutter ( 6926): #6      MIDApi.getLooks.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/libraries/api.dart)
E/flutter ( 6926): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6926): #7      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1381:54)
E/flutter ( 6926): #8      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
E/flutter ( 6926): #9      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:633:45)
E/flutter ( 6926): #10     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:662:32)
E/flutter ( 6926): #11     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:467:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #12     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 6926): #13     ajaxGet (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/libraries/ajax.dart)
E/flutter ( 6926): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6926): #14     MIDApi.getItems (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/libraries/api.dart:22:5)
E/flutter ( 6926): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6926): #15     _LandingPageState.doSomething (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/pages/landing.dart:129:39)
E/flutter ( 6926): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6926): #16     _LandingPageState._handleTap (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/pages/landing.dart:124:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #17     _LandingPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/Development/myapp/lib/pages/landing.dart:61:26)
E/flutter ( 6926): #18     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter ( 6926): #19     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
E/flutter ( 6926): #20     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:123:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #21     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 6926): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:147:20)
E/flutter ( 6926): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
E/flutter ( 6926): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #25     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #26     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
E/flutter ( 6926): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:13)
E/flutter ( 6926): #28     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:5)
Reloaded 15 of 522 libraries in 634ms.
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I want a generic method to handle all my HttpRequest towards my Web Server.  In regular Javascript, a Promise (Future in Dart) is generic and you may return Promise as an answer of another Promise.  I also tried to use the Completer but the result is the same.

Comment: That should work. I'm not able to derive from your code what exactly is going on.

Comment: It looks like the fact of returning ajaxGet(url) which is a Future<String> does not please the system.

Comment: I think you'd better await ajaxGet(url) and after that you can just return the PageAnswer.

Comment: When I am changing the signature to Future<dynamic> getItems, I don't receive the first exception (at first call) but I have the second exception, when the ajaxGet(url) returns the new PageAnswer(objects, total).  This exception says "type '() => Type' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr<Objects>'

Comment: @Rene  I also tried it but then I have the following exception:  type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Comment: Are you actually returning `Null` instead of `null`?  `Null` is the type object representing `null`, that might be an issue